# How to display some editor functions in Richface's editor while the readonly attribute is set to true?

Tags: jsf, tinymce, richfaces

While working on a legacy application using Seam 2.2, jsf 1.2, and Richfaces 3.3, I encountered the following problem:

When an item is in draft mode and therefore editable, I have a nice-looking editor for entering and formatting text. After the text and the item passes some administrator's approval, it is not editable anymore (see last attribute - readonly):

```
<rich:editor id="a" 
   value="#{pReq.comment}" 
   configuration="editorconfig" 
   autoResize="true" 
   useSeamText="true" 
   theme="advanced" 
   plugins="fullscreen" 
   style="width: 100%;" 
   readonly="#{form.isEditable()}" >
```

When displaying the same page now, I immediately loose all of the Richfaces editor's functionality and have just an ugly small textfield. I still need some functionality, however, such as the fullscreen toggle.

Anybody has an idea to make the readonly attribute work less "radical"?

Comment: They're using CKEditor under the hood. Check the richfaces showcase and the ckeditor to see if you can get what you need. http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=editor&sample=advancedConfiguration&skin=blueSky http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_readonly

Comment: @axemoi RichFaces 3 uses [tinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/)

Comment: That is correct, it is tinyMCE 3 https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/. I will post my solution as soon as I.am done working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting 'readonly=false', richfaces Editor will always revert to a simple textbox. Therefore, this attribute is useless in this case. Instead, I solved the problem by using two separate configuration.properties files to achieve my goal.

The xhtml loads the appropriate properties file depending on the Parameter 'configFile':

```
<rich:editor id="pLRiTa" value="#{pReq.comment}"
         autoResize="true" useSeamText="false"
         configuration="#{configFile}"
         oninit="tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', #{isEditable});">
<f:param name="save_enablewhendirty" value="true" />
<f:param name="save_onsavecallback" value="savenow" />
```

The configuration properties file with edit enabled is:

```
theme="advanced"
width="100%"
plugins="save,paste,fullscreen"
save_enablewhendirty="true"
save_onsavecallback="savenow"
    theme_advanced_buttons1="bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,cut,separator,forecolor,backcolor,separator,save,separator,fullscreen"
theme_advanced_buttons2="bullist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator,cleanup,help,code"
    theme_advanced_buttons3="pastetext,pasteword,selectall,separator,removeformat,visualaid,separator,sub,sup,separator,charmap"
theme_advanced_toolbar_location="top"
theme_advanced_toolbar_align="left"
```

The configuration properties file with edit disabled is:

```
theme="advanced"
plugins="fullscreen"
theme_advanced_buttons1="fullscreen"
theme_advanced_buttons2=""
theme_advamced_buttons3=""
theme_advanced_toolbar_location="top"
theme_advanced_toolbar_align="left"
width="100%"
```

And the 'savenow' is defined as follows:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="savenow" id="savenowid"
        action="#{plEditModalController.saveWithoutClosing()}"
        ignoreDupResponses="true" immediate="false" process="plEditAll"
        oncomplete="console.log('saved')"/>
```